# Stop tkinter treeivew from deselecting?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a treeview and I don't want it to deselect items so easily. I mainly don't want it to deselect everything when I'm trying to expand a parent node.

Is there any way that I can manage treeview deselection with buttons rather than leave it all to the widget?

Comment: Yes there are ways to achieve this

Comment: elaboration would be nice

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is:

- set `selectmode='none'` to disable selection on mouse left click
- bind mouse right click to a callback and select the item which is clicked inside the callback.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode='none')
tree.pack()

# insert dummy data
for i in range(5):
    node = tree.insert('', 'end', text=f'Node {i+1}')
    for j in range(3):
        tree.insert(node, 'end', text=f'Sub-note {i+1}.{j+1}')

def on_right_clicked(event):
    row = tree.identify('row', event.x, event.y)
    if row:
        # select clicked item
        tree.selection_set(row)

tree.bind('<3>', on_right_clicked)

root.mainloop()
```

Then expanding a parent node does not select the node.

---

Update: if multiple selections is required, then replace `tree.selection_set(...)` by `tree.selection_toggle(...)`.

Comment: This does solve the parent expansion problem, but it removes the ability to select multiple items, which is essential for the program I'm making.

Comment: @SlaveCat You can use `selection_toggle(row)` instead of `selection_set(row)` to have multiple selections.

Comment: @SlavaCat Please note, that [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) is part of the deal here.